# How to optimize my linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
 List<string> res = new List<string>();
                var all = data.Select(c => new 
                {
                    All = db.Costs.Where(d => d.IdInformation == c.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(f => new 
                    {
                        Summ = f.All.HasValue ? f.All.Value : 0,
                        BA = f.BA.HasValue ? f.BA.Value : 0,
                        BK = f.BK.HasValue ? f.BK.Value : 0,
                        BT = f.BT.HasValue ? f.BT.Value : 0,
                        Cash = f.Cash.HasValue ? f.Cash.Value : 0
                    })
                }).Select(g => new
                   {
                       Summ1 = g.All.Sum(h => h.Summ)/g.All.Count(),
                       Nad1 = g.All.Sum(j => j.BA+j.BK+j.BT+j.Cash),
                   });
                var summ = all.Sum(c => c.Summ1);
                var nad = all.Sum(c => c.Nad1);
                res.Add(summ.ToString());
                res.Add(nad.ToString());
                res.Add((summ-nad).ToString());
                return res;
```

My query very long excecuted, how to optimize this?
where data is iqueryable
help please
My query very long excecuted, how to optimize this?
where data is iqueryable
help please

```
{SELECT ((
    SELECT SUM([t4].[value])
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t3].[All] IS NOT NULL THEN [t3].[All]
                ELSE @p2
             END) AS [value]
        FROM (
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            ) AS [t1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT [t2].[All]
            FROM [dbo].[Costs] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[IdInformation] = ([t0].[Id])
            ) AS [t3] ON 1=1 
        ) AS [t4]
    )) / (CONVERT(Float,(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        ) AS [t5]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[Costs] AS [t6]
        WHERE [t6].[IdInformation] = ([t0].[Id])
        ) AS [t7] ON 1=1 
    ))) AS [Summ1], (
    SELECT SUM([t11].[value] + [t11].[value2] + [t11].[value3] + [t11].[value4])
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t10].[BA] IS NOT NULL THEN [t10].[BA]
                ELSE @p3
             END) AS [value], 
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t10].[BK] IS NOT NULL THEN [t10].[BK]
                ELSE @p4
             END) AS [value2], 
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t10].[BT] IS NOT NULL THEN [t10].[BT]
                ELSE @p5
             END) AS [value3], 
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t10].[Cash] IS NOT NULL THEN [t10].[Cash]
                ELSE @p6
             END) AS [value4]
        FROM (
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            ) AS [t8]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT [t9].[BT], [t9].[BA], [t9].[BK], [t9].[Cash]
            FROM [dbo].[Costs] AS [t9]
            WHERE [t9].[IdInformation] = ([t0].[Id])
            ) AS [t10] ON 1=1 
        ) AS [t11]
    ) AS [Nad1]
FROM [dbo].[Information] AS [t0]
WHERE (CONVERT(NVarChar,DATEPART(Year, [t0].[DateAdd]))) IN (@p0, @p1)
}
```

this sql generated my code, i using linq-to-sql

Comment: Your code performs multiple aggregation operations (Sum()). If you are using an ORM, this results in multiple queries to the database at best. Anyway, ORMs aren't meant for reporting. It's easier and much faster to create an appropriate SQL view that returns your data and map it than try to approximate the SQL query with LINQ

Comment: How much time is being taken up by the database (assume you have one since you have an `IQueryable`)? Can you optimise that part? Are you repeating the same operation on the DB: can you get that data once and process multiple times in memory? (If your DB is SQL Server then SQL Profiler is very helpful, other DBs have similar capabilities.